# How to make all cores work during scipi linalg solver?

Tags: python, computation

I wrote an algorithm for Newmark integration of equation of motion. It works quite well, with the main solver set up as `scipy.linalg.solve`, however as far as i have been told this solver should use whole CPU but for my calculations it's only using one core. Can you please tell me what should i change / where the mistake is? Code of the main solver part below.

```py
for i in range (1,NT):

    t=dt*i
    V1=(a1*U[:,i-1]+a4*Ud[:,i-1]+a5*Udd[:,i-1])
    V2=(a0*U[:,i-1]+a2*Ud[:,i-1]+a3*Udd[:,i-1])

    print("calculation in timestep t=", t)

    CV=dot(numpy.array(Ceqbb).astype(numpy.float64),V1)
    MA=dot(numpy.array(Beqbb).astype(numpy.float64),V2)


    #  apply forces

    F=(numpy.array(FQbb(t)).astype(numpy.float64)).reshape(ndof)


    FH=F+MA+CV

#  solve for displacements

    if(ndof>1):
        Un = linalg.solve(KHnn(t), FH)
    else:
        Un=FH/KHnn(t)

    Uddn=a0*(Un-U[:,i-1])-a2*Ud[:,i-1]-a3*Udd[:,i-1]
    Udn=Ud[:,i-1]+a6*Udd[:,i-1]+a7*Uddn


    U[:,i]=Un
    Ud[:,i]=Udn
    Udd[:,i]=Uddn
```

Comment: How do you know it uses only one?

Comment: You should take a look at Multithread/Parallel Programming for your framework. [This](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html) might be a starting point. Try your changes and keep paying attention to your CPU usage.